# Cannot ssh/ping server but can ssh/ping other servers all on the same network

Tags: 14.04, networking, ssh, routing

I have a situation where a computer (A) I can ping/ssh to other computers (B/ C) on the same subnet as a server (S) but cannot ping or ssh to S.

Both B and C can both connect to s1 normally and connect to A normally.

I've been digging into reasons why and I suspect that there is an issue with the routing table

on B and C (which work)

```
$ ip route
default via 128.218.162.1 dev enx000acd295212 proto dhcp metric 100 
128.218.162.0/24 dev enx000acd295212 proto kernel scope link src 128.218.162.132 metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx000acd295212 scope link metric 1000 

$ ip addr show dev enx000acd295212
8: enx000acd295212: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:0a:cd:29:52:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 128.218.162.132/24 brd 128.218.162.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx000acd295212
   valid_lft 587218sec preferred_lft 587218sec
inet6 fe80::b8e3:8728:9e1d:a695/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

on cA (broken)

```
$ ip route
default via 128.218.162.1 dev eth0  metric 100 
128.218.162.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 128.218.162.41 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000 

$ ip addr show eth0 
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:24:9b:29:dd:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 128.218.162.41/24 brd 128.218.162.255 scope global eth0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::224:9bff:fe29:ddea/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

S1 is on 128.218.162.39

Pings to S1 from A are being returned by A's IP

```
 $ ping 128.218.162.39
 PING 128.218.162.39 (128.218.162.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
 From 128.218.162.41 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
 From 128.218.162.41 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
 From 128.218.162.41 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the IP address of the server? Can the server reach A? Please add the _full_ output of `ip route` to your question (note that if S is on one subnet with A, B, and C, then the default route is irrelevant). Also, please add the output of `ip addr show dev eth0` on A and `ip addr show dev enx000acd295212` on B or C.

Comment: Edited to include information, thanks for taking the time to help out! No the server can't reach out to A.

Comment: The routes and subnets all look perfectly sane to me, and all machines can reach each other, except for A and S. Just to be sure: when you `ping S` from A you see S's correct IP? Does the output of `ip neigh show 128.218.162.39`on A give `REACHABLE` and the correct MAC address? (Cross check with output on B or C.) And vice versa when run for A from S? When all this is good too, then one of them must be dropping packages from the other: firewall? Final option: diagnose with `tcpdump`, `wireshark`, or the like.

Comment: So on A it shows REACHABLE and the correct MAC address, but on B/C it shows it as STALE. Ping hangs on A and works fine for B and C

Comment: Did you missed something in cut&paste or is the second line for ip route on cA really doesn't have a metric value at the end?

Comment: @BernardWei metrics are optional on routes. Note: A is reachable from B and C and vice versa.

Comment: @BernardWei it doesn't have a metric value

Comment: Try delete it and add one that have a metric like the one you have on cB and cC. I.e., First deleting, `sudo ip route del 128.218.162.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 128.218.162.41`, then add one with metric 100, `sudo ip route add 128.218.162.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 128.218.162.41 metric 100`

Comment: Nope no difference